# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS from Classic Load Balancer in AWS

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

We have a web application developed in `Asp.NET MVC Core 3.1`. Deployed it using `Elastic Beanstalk`.
Configured `Classic load balancer` for this with AWS issued certificate listener. Our classic load balancer's listeners configured as below.
[image]
[image]
Using this setting, its not redirecting from `Http` to `Https`. However if we try to access website individually with Https and Http its working fine.

We don't want to change Load Balancer Type from Classic to Application as the environment is already setup in Route S3 too.

Can you please help if anything missing in this?